# Hibernate criteria results

Tags: java, hibernate

I think this is a very simple question. but unfortunately I cannot find a solution.
I have a mysql database table called "Invoice" having "inv_No","inv_netvalue","inv_date" inv_No is the primary key. I want to get a Invoice object according to a given inv_No.  I used a critaria. But this result nothing. `list.size()`  is 0.

```
        Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
        invoice.setInvNo(Integer.parseInt(invoiceNo));
        Session session = HSession.getSession();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Invoice.class);
        crit.add(Example.create(invoice));
        List list=crit.list();
```

but when I used this `"FROM Invoice invoice WHERE invoice.invNo='" + invoiceNo + "'"`  it returns which I expected.

Any one help me please.Let me know where I am wrong..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you've got the second createCriteria call. Have you tried this?

```
 Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Invoice.class);
 crit.add(Example.create(invoice));
```

That follows some of the [examples in the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html), for example.

EDIT: Another option is not to use "query by example" but just:

```
 Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Invoice.class);
 crit.add.(Restrictions.eq("invNo", Integer.parseInt(invoiceNo)));
```

Comment: Yes,no point in second critaria. I tried changing code many ways..with your code as well.but it didn't work yet

Comment: @AashMaharoon: Have you tried looking at the log for what's being sent in the SQL? Also see my edited answer with another alternative.

Comment: Thank you so much. That eq worked well. Actually I wanted to know where the problem is in code(to solve future problems). and tried with different tables but no result :(  any way now my question was solved.

Comment: I am using Netbeans 7.01 and I tried to get sql logs in Netbeans. but I couldn't. Could you let me know how I can see the logs in Netbeans. Thank you. logs cannt be seen in normal console. but only SessionFactor starting. Thank you

Comment: @AashMaharoon: I'm afraid it's *ages* since I've done any Hibernate, and I've never used Netbeans - but I'm sure there should be plenty of docs about setting up logging.

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Invoice.class);
criteria.add.(Restrictions.eq("invNo", Integer.parseInt(invoiceNo)));
```

is the best way to get the results.

Comment: difference is what except variable name?